# Why is "at least" commoner than "at the least" but "at very least" is less common than "at the very least"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

The tl;dr version is the title plus, the last paragraph. FWIW, some background really helps.

**Background**: I have always thought *at least* and *at the very least* are the grammatical and idiomatic phrases I could use. Today, I ran into this comment:

> Welcome to Chem.SE! This appears to be a homework question. Please see the policy on posting homework questions here; **at the least**, please include more details on your thought process so far in trying to answer this question. - [Brian](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/11367/brian) [yesterday](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33032/can-someone-indicate-which-chemicals-are-oxidized-and-reduced-in-this-equation#comment49150_33032)

This raised my alarm for being ungrammatical; however, as [free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/least) says, *at the least* does exist, so does *at very least*:
[image]

[image]

**Question**: Now this is very baffling. *At least* doesn't have a definite article, while *at the very least* does. They are so much more common than their "evil twins" that I reckon some would only consider **them** grammatical.

So, my question is why? What does the definite article *the* indicate in *at the very least* that it doesn't and shouldn't in *at least*? This doesn't seem to be a matter of pure stylic choice, as there seems to be a consensus about which version of the idioms to use.

---

**Edit**: I'm not looking to find contextual differences. I'm concerned about a grammatical explanation about what's going on.

Comment: You should add some actual examples you found using each phrase in question. Otherwise we are doing the research or guessing what the context differences might be.

Comment: @user3169 I'm not actually looking for differences in context. I'm looking for a grammatical explanation.

Comment: Can you show us an example that uses *"at very least"*?

Comment: I think I'm familiar with the usages: "(the (very)) least". But the usage *"at very least"* seems somewhat not so familiar to me--and so, I'm interested in seeing how and when it is/was used.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is *at very least* so uncommon compared to *at the very least*?

Because *at the very least* is valid syntax while *at very least* is not. Without a definite article, the word ***very*** is an adverb that describes additional (positive or negative) magnitude. The word ***least*** describes a concept that by definition cannot receive additional magnitude (the smallest thing ***isn't*** the smallest thing if there is something smaller).

> What does the definite article ***the*** indicate in *at the very least* that it doesn't and shouldn't in *at least*?

The definite article allows the word ***very*** to act as an adjective meaning "*genuine; true in the fullest sense of the word; precise; particular*" instead of trying to increase its magnitude. These are modifiers which the word *least* can accept.